# How do I upload FIle in Vuejs and Expressjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, multer

Hey please am new to Vuejs and Express...So am trying to practice.

So am trying to create a User Profile with comes with a image Using Vuejs and ExpressJs but none of the file or text is uploading.

This is my **CreateProfile.vue** file

```
       <div class="icon-pic">
       <label for="Password">Upload your Logo / Picture</label>
        <input type="file" ref="file" @change="handleFileUpload"/>
      </div>

      <b-input-group class="mb-2">
        <b-form-input
          id="input-small"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your Name"
          required
          :rules="[rules.required]"
          v-model="profile.fullname"
        ></b-form-input>

        <b-form-input
          id="input-small"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your BrandName"
          v-model="profile.brandname"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-input-group>
```

**Note**: There are other inputs...

Below is my script functions for the form

```
<script>
import ProfileService from '@/services/ProfileService'

export default {
data () {
return {
  profile: {
    fullname: null,
    brandname: null,
    skill1: null,
    skill2: null,
    skill3: null,
    skill4: null,
    socail_handle1: null,
    socail_handle2: null
  },
  file: null,
  error: null,
  rules: {
    required: (value) => !!value || 'Required.'
  }
}},
methods: {
handleFileUpload () {
  const file = this.$refs.file.files[0]
  this.file = file
},
async create () {
  this.error = null
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', this.files)
  const areAllFieldsFilledIn = Object.keys(this.profile).every(
    (key) => !!this.profile[key]
  )
  if (!areAllFieldsFilledIn) {
    this.error = 'Please fill in all the required fields.'
    return
  }
  try {
    await ProfileService.post(this.profile, formData)
    this.$router.push({
      name: 'profile'
    })
  } catch (error) {
    this.error = error.response.data.error
  }
}}}
```

Below is my **ProfileController.js** file

```
const {Profile} = require ('../models')
const multer = require ('multer')

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
const allowedTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]
if (!allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)){
const err = new Error('Incorrect File');
return cb(err, false)
}
cb(null, true)
}

const upload = multer ({
dest: '../public',
fileFilter,
})

module.exports = {
async post (req, res){
    try {
        upload.single('files')
        const profile = await new Profile({
        profile: this.profile,
        files: req.file
      });
      profile.save().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(201).json({
          message: "Done upload!"
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send({
        error: 'An Error has occured trying to fetch'
    })}}
```

Follow by my **Model/Profile.js** file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Profile = sequelize.define('Profile', {
     files: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON
     },
     fullname: {
       type: DataTypes.STRING,
       allowNull: false
     },
     brandname: DataTypes.STRING,
     skill1: DataTypes.STRING,
     skill2: DataTypes.STRING,
     skill3: DataTypes.STRING,
     skill4: DataTypes.STRING,
     socail_handle1: DataTypes.STRING,
     socail_handle2: DataTypes.STRING
 })
 return Profile 
 }
```

I hope any one can help me with this please!!!

This is my **route.js** file

```
const AuthController = require('./controllers/AuthController')
const AuthControllerPolicy = require('./policies/AuthControllerPolicy')
const ProfileControler = require('./controllers/ProfileController')
const upload = require ('multer')

module.exports = (app) => {
app.post('/register',
    AuthControllerPolicy.register,
    AuthController.register)

app.post('/login',
    AuthController.login)

app.get('/profile',
    ProfileControler.index)
    
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),
    ProfileControler.upload)
```

}

Comment: Perhaps checkout [Uppy with Vue.js](https://uppy.io/docs/vue/) - I know it's not a proper answer and it depends on if your requirements is creating your own uploader or if you just want simple file uploading in Vue. I am not affiliated with them in any way and it's not really a proper answer but I have used Uppy in the past and it seems to make these things a bit easier.

Comment: Will check that out 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice two things:

1. You're not using multer as a middleware function

`upload.single('file')` returns a function which should be passed as a middleware in your Express routes. You can use it like this in your `route.js`:

```js
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({
  dest: '../public',
  fileFilter,
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), ProfileController.post);
```

Then you can remove the upload code in your post function:

```js
module.exports.post = async (req, res) => {
  // Multer makes your file available at req.file
  const file = req.file;

  try {
    // Don't need to await when creating a new Mongo object
    const profile = new Profile({
      profile: this.profile,
      files: file
    });

    // Refactored this to use async/await instead of promises.
    // Avoid mixing promises with async/await.
    const result = await profile.save();
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "Done upload!" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).send({ error: 'An Error has occured trying to fetch' });
  }
}
```

2. The name of the file input passed to multer doesn't match with frontend

You're configuring multer to look for a file input named `files`: `upload.single('files')`, yet in the frontend you're naming it `file` (singular): `formData.append('file', this.files)`. Usually multer will then throw an [unexpected field error](https://maximorlov.com/fix-unexpected-field-error-multer/). Make sure these two match *exactly*.

This free guide for [Parsing Requests in Node.js](https://maximorlov.com/request-parsing-nodejs-guide/) will help you handle file uploads in Node.js.

Comment: Thanks so much...I will try that.

Comment: So @maximOrlov Since i have added the `upload.single('file')` to my route. How should my upload method look like?                                                                
        `upload.single('files') const profile = await new Profile({profile: this.profile, files: req.file`   Please!!!

Comment: If you post your routes file (where you import ` ProfileController.js`), I can adjust my answer to fit your question.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the new `post` method. Change your router to use `ProfileController.post` not `ProfileController.upload` since the method you're exporting is called `post`. I've also refactored the `post` method a little bit, read the comments.

Comment: Thanks so much ...I will adjust it

Comment: You're welcome! If the issue is fixed make sure to mark the answer as resolved so others can find it in the future. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank so much, I think am almost there. but only that `const upload = multer ({
dest: '../public',
fileFilter,
})` this code in profileController.js file, the upload is assigned but not used. How do i make use of it, or what could be the other alternative way to go about it.

Comment: Move that part to your route.js file. I'll edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233343/discussion-between-hemmyhtec-creatives-and-maxim-orlov).